# How to implement MonadFix instance of an IO-like type in JS?

Tags: javascript, haskell, monads, monadfix

I am completely lost in trying to translate the following Haskell code into Javascript:

```
instance MonadFix IO where
  mfix f = do
    var <- newEmptyMVar                       -- 1
    ans <- unsafeInterleaveIO $ takeMVar var  -- 2
    result <- f ans                           -- 3
    putMVar var result                        -- 4
    return result                             -- 5
```

> Let’s walk through this line by line in terms of our little time
> travel analogy:
>
> 1. Create an empty mutable variable.
> 2. Predict the future value that will be contained in that mutable variable.
> 3. Call the function f with the predicted future value.
> 4. Store the result of f in the variable, thus fulfilling the prophecy as required by line 2.
> 5. Return that result.

What I have is a special `Lazy` type that handles (or rather defers) synchronous `IO`. However, I'd like to abstract from direct recursion with value recursion:

```js
const record = (type, o) =>
  (o[Symbol.toStringTag] = type.name || type, o);

const Lazy = lazy => record(Lazy, {get lazy() {
  delete this.lazy
  return this.lazy = lazy();
}});

// Monad

const lazyChain = mx => fm =>
  Lazy(() => fm(mx.lazy).lazy);

const lazyChain_ = fm => mx =>
  Lazy(() => fm(mx.lazy).lazy);

const lazyOf = x => Lazy(() => x);

// mfix = chain_ => fm => chain_(fm) (mfix(chain_) (fm)) ???

// MAIN

const trace = x => (console.log(x), x);
const app_ = x => f => trace(f(x));

const readLine = s => Lazy(() => window.prompt(s));

const fac = x => x === 0 ? 1 : x * fac(x - 1),
  tri = x => x === 0 ? 0 : x + tri(x - 1);

const foo = lazyChain(readLine("enter true/false")) (s => {
  return lazyOf(s === "true"
    ? fac : tri);
});

const bar = x => lazyChain(foo) (y => lazyOf(app_(x) (y)));
const main = bar(5);

console.log("effect has not yet been unleashed..");
main.lazy;
```

How do I implement the `Lazy` instance of `MonadFix` in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You have a representation of *thunks* with your `Lazy` construct, which happens to form a monad (where monadic application is just strict function application, as you’ve written), but you don’t have a representation of `IO`, so you’re essentially just using `unsafePerformIO` everywhere.

In your model, each I/O action can only be executed once, so I expect this will *not* work quite the way you expect unless you add a separate `IO` wrapper with something like a `runIO` function (or property, if you like) that does *not* share `Lazy`’s behaviour of overwriting itself with the memoised result, or perhaps if you add some way to explicitly duplicate a deferred action. Of course, `mfix f` only runs the effects of `f` once anyway—that is, it’s for *using* effects to produce a lazy/self-referential data structure—so this may be fine for your purposes.

Those caveats aside, it’s perfectly possible to express something resembling an instance of `MonadFix` for your thunk structure, but it’s just a lazy version of `fix`:

```
// cf. Haskell ‘fix f = let ans = f ans in ans’
function lazyFix(f) {
  var ans = Lazy(() => f(ans));
  return ans;
}
```

If you have side effects interleaved in these thunks, they’ll happen as you force them.

I think the `MVar` business in the original Haskell code is mainly just a convenient way to catch a subset of infinite loops, by ensuring that if the action tries to force the thunk *before* a value is written into it, then the runtime will be able to detect that the thread is “blocked indefinitely in an `MVar` operation” and raise an error.

And as a side note, you should be able to simplify your `lazyChain` definition to just `fm(mx.lazy)`, since `Lazy(() => fm(mx.lazy).lazy)` forces the result and then immediately wraps it in a thunk again, which is both extra work and possibly too eager about your interleaved effects. Your version is effectively `` let fx = fm mx in mx `seq` fx `seq` fx ``, which can be simplified (by `` a `seq` a `` = `a`) to `` mx `seq` fm mx ``, which is then equivalent to `fm $! mx`, i.e., strict function application.

Comment: The `MVar` in that code was a bit "belt and suspenders". The current implementation uses `unsafeDupableInterleaveIO` and relies on the `MVar` for thread safety.

Comment: Hmm... Actually, I think when it was written, `unsafeInterleaveIO` might not have been thread safe? I don't remember. Anyway, things are pretty reasonable now....

Comment: Yes, each `.lazy` lookup is equivalent to `unsafePerformIO`. I can still benefit from `Lazy`, because it defers effects, makes them composable and I only run them at the edge of my application. There is another type `Defer` w/o sharing. I've learned that "aggressive" sharing is a good feature when you work with impure code, b/c it helpfs with non-idempotent effects.

Comment: JS actually does not evaluate the thunk literal `() => fm(mx.lazy).lazy` in `Lazy(() => fm(mx.lazy).lazy)`, but only when `.lazy` is looked up on it. If I only had `fm(mx.lazy)` it'd be too eager, because `fm` would be invoked immediately witht the result of the effect of `mx`.